# Am I making a mistake when qualifying values with MySQL? I have run several versions of the same query but each of them won't output anything

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am currently trying to solve an SQL exercise that asks me to get following attributes: "order number", "item number", and "description" for every order that was placed on the date of October 12, 2015. I have to use three different tables in this exercise meaning I have to qualify values in order to get MySQL to understand what I'm asking it to give me.

The tables are the following:

[image: This is the item table.]

The Item table relates to the Order Line table because of the "ITEM_NUM" column.

[image: This is the Order line table.]

This table relates to the Item and Orders table because it has columns for "ORDER_NUM" and "ITEM_NUM".

[image: This is the Orders table.]

This table relates to the Order Line table because of the "ORDER_NUM" column.

Now here's the issue, I wrote several versions of the following (I only posted one for convenience) and they all run...

[image: this query]

None of them give me errors from MySQL but the result output is totally blank. As you can see, I am qualifying the values of each table so that MySQL know specifically which attribute I'm talking about and avoid ambiguity. I am also equalling the matching attributes from the different tables.

The output should be `51608, CD33, Wood Block Set (48 piece)` for one order and `51610, KL78, Pick Up Sticks` for the second order. These are the only orders that occur on October 12, 2015.

I only have one theory as to what my be happening. When I created this database in MySQL, I made a mistake when creating the Orders table. I had to drop it and create it again. But I'm starting to think that somehow, MySQL is still working with the first table Orders table I made and not the New Orders table.

Comment: Don't show images add text  for queries and data see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

Following should give you the expected result. For the best practice always use `join` when you have to deal with multiple tables.

```
select
    ol.order_num,
    ol.item_num,
    i.description,
    i.category
from items i

join order_line ol
on i.item_num = ol.item_num

join orders o
on ol.order_num = o.order_num

where order_date = '2015/10/12'
```